# How to create a “virtual” or “temporary” Role for a user under ASP.NET MVC 5 that will still work with controller and method decorations?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roles

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.7.2
- MVC 5
- C# 7.2
- [Repository Pattern](https://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/)

I am a bit stumped on how to create a “virtual” Role under MVC 5.

Normal (persistent) roles I fully understand: you create them in the DB and then assign a user to that role. However, I need to assign a user to a “Role” depending on a status in a completely unrelated table, and where that Role only exists during their session - it does not exist for that user before they log in, and it no longer exists for that user once their session ends.

> So for example, since the Active status is dependent on whether a user
>   is on leave or not, let’s call this table the “on leave” table. Very
>   simple: primary key, user id foreign key, a required start date and an
>   optional end date. When a user logs in, I need to flag the user as
>   either fully active (an actual Active role for just that session) or
>   inactive (no Active role for that session). This will be determined by
>   whether,
>
> 1. The user has an entry in the “on leave” table, and if so,
> 2. The most recent entry has,
>
>    1. A null end date, or
>    2. An end date in the future
>
> If the user has an entry in the table, and the most recent entry has a
>   null end date or an end date in the future, the user does not get the
>   Active role. If they don’t meet that requirement, they do get that
>   role.

This is just one of a number of requirements on the site that will require virtual roles, but is a simplified example to get the point across.

This is also very important because **about 95-99% of my needs revolves around the controller and method decorations and session authorizations** - I need to be able to `[Authorize(Roles = "Active")]` and `User.Identity.IsInRole("Active")`, but I want that role to exist for the user *only for that session*.

Please understand that the underlying data is fully dynamic: if the data on the back end changes to something that invalidates them for Active status, I want their next login to *not* include the Active role being applied to their session. *This* is why I am trying to work with a “virtual” or “temporary” role that the user is *not* directly associated with in terms of the in-DB data.

Now if it was just one thing that was being checked for (like the On Leave table), I *could* just ensure that adding an end date would add the user to a fully traditional Active role, but the problem exists for entries in the future -- how would I go around auto-adding the user to that role once that date passes, at least without doing a database-write-and-login-bounce to properly set their authentication and session variables?

Plus, this is just one item of many that need to work in concert to provide a yes/no determination for Active status. This Active status will be drawn from not *just* the most current entry of the On Leave table, but also a number of different business rules from around the system that *can* be retrieved from the initial fetching of the user’s profile through `_userManager`, and all of them being virtual booleans providing a simple cumulative yes-no answer.

The point is, this Active role status will never touch the database, or even need to. This will *always* be in the context of the currently logged-in user, **set when they log in, and dumped/destroyed when they time out or log out.**

I suspect that the place to do this is in the `SignInAsync` where I set all my Claims, I just don’t know how to do this to the user’s session.

If someone can throw some hints on how to set up a virtual Role there, that the system (controller and method decorations) can work with, that would be real swell.

---

As requested, my login implementation:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);
if(user != null) {
  SignInAsync(user, false).Wait();
  // Bounce the user to the "Nexus" method, that determines where they should go based on Role, so that the Role can actually be read once it is in the User’s context.
}
```

And my `SignInAsync()` Task:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(IdentityUser user, bool isPersistent) {
  AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
  var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
  identity.AddClaim(new UserClaim.Claim("ShortName", user.ShortName));
  identity.AddClaim(new UserClaim.Claim("Name", user.Name));
  // Snipped for brevity
  AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Comment: How do you authenticate and authorize user currently? Could you show your implementation?

Comment: Added login implementation.

Comment: In current application, how do you add role after login. Could you not able to add dynamic role?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do: add a role to a user’s session without actually assigning a role to that user in the DB. I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Microsoft is going toward `Claims` based authorization. In ASP.NET Identity, roles are there for backward compatibility.

However, you can still set role as Claim. For example,

`claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));`

You then apply `Authorize` attribute to controller or action method as `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

[Here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs#L30) is the sample code at GitHub.

Comment: And this will work with the controller and method decorators, without modification?